# Timeline JS Transparent Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline.js

I spent hours and hours working both with local files, CDNs, etc etc. And the only way I got the timeline showing was using the **embeded js** . For more information on the JS I am talking about: https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS#config-options

So my code looks like something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="timeline"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline/latest/js/storyjs-embed.js"></script>
```

JS

```
createStoryJS({
        type:       'timeline',
        width:      '100%',
        height:     '600',
        source:     'my json or excel,
        embed_id:   'timeline'           // ID of the DIV you want to load the timeline into
    });
```

Once again, to gain more power over the css and js files I **DID** try downloading the css and js files manually and could not make them to appear.

Now first of, I think I should still be able to override the css settings even though its a CDN (Or can I **not**?), I spent hours trying to find the right class and ID to make the background transparent (Or at least the color of my choice).

I also tried this document but alot of stuff used in it where outdated and caused issues with jQuery and so on: http://tutorialzine.com/2012/04/timeline-portfolio/

I would really really appreciate it if someone could find this mysterious class/ID so that I can customize this thing. Thanks In advance.

**EDIT**

To make this easier to understand, Have this codepen for example: http://codepen.io/salmanjalali87/pen/oXMjmy
I got the color working and I can change the color (kind of). But I cant put an image there. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I got lost on your post, very confused, here is the code just to make it work

(1) - you place this in the **< head>**

```
<script src="http://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline/latest/js/storyjs-embed.js"></script>
```

(2) - you put your div inside html

```
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

(3) - you place the **createStoryJS({});**

Right after the **storyjs-embed.js** library call inside a **script** tag and inside a **document ready**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

createStoryJS({
    type:       'timeline',
    width:      '100%',
    height:     '600',
    source:     'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZNs-5eEMGbrIup1ZSj3Ovga-8wF2bVdNTBAiXFl08M/edit#gid=0',
    embed_id:   'timeline'           // ID of the DIV you want to load the timeline into
});
```

});

Comment: Lol you did nothing but restate my question :) I know my way around getting it to show. The question is that I want to override some of the css attributes to change the background color from white (ie make it transparent). I want to know those selectors and so on if that makes sense.

Comment: Appreciate the effort though